# Laravel update multi rows using whereIn

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

I have ids in a string through ajax,

example:

```
"1,2"
```

and in my controller, I would like to update multiple rows of a product in one query using **whereIn** with id => `[1,2]`.

**ajax:**

```
$('#add_product').click(function() { 
   var id = $('#get_value').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{action('ProductController@updateProduct')}}",
        data: {
        id: id
        },
     success: function(data){
          alert("success");
     }
    });
});
```

**Controller :**

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
 $test_value = collect($request->id);
 $updateProduct = Product::whereIn('id',$test_value)
                  ->update(['title' => 'My title']);
}
```

But i have this error in the network :

**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,2' (SQL: update "products" set "title" = "My title" where "id" in (1,2))**

Comment: just dd($test_value) show the output

Comment: dd($test_value) show's me => "1,2"

Comment: @sebastianlarsen have you overcome this problem with my answer?

Comment: @ChiragPatel, yes thank's it works very well (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **$test_value** you are getting values `"1,2"` as a string so you have to make it array first with using **explode()** function(what explode() function do is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)),

```
$ids = explode(',',$test_value);
```

then pass this `$ids` into your function.

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
    $test_value = $request->id;
    $ids = explode(',',$test_value);
    $updateProduct = Product::whereIn('id',$ids)
                  ->update(['title' => 'My title']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **collect()**

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
   $test_value = $request->id;
   $ids = explode( ',',$test_value);
   $updateProduct = Product::whereIn('id',$ids)
              ->update(['title' => 'My title']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not update the fields in the table - bulk. You need to update one by one through the foreach

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
 $updateProducts = [];

 foreach((array) $request->id as $id) {
  $updateProducts[] = Product::where('id', $id)
                                      ->first()
                                      ->update(['title' => 'My title']);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank's Mike Foxtech , but he make me an update for id = 1 but for id = 2 he does not do anything

Comment: @sebastianlarsen **$request->id** looks like an array, that's right [1, 2] ?

Comment: You CAN bulk update the fields in a table. In fact, if you are not specific enough; your query will affect all the table.